# CSS responsive menu

Tags: html, css

I am having problem in my responsive menu. When i click the menu navigation, all the list is show horizontal. But i want it to be vertical which means that only 1 list in 1 line. Please help me, i am new to programming

```css
    .menu ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {

      display: none;

    }

    .menu ul.topnav li.icon {

      display: inline-block;

      float: right;

    }

    .menu ul.topnav.responsive {

      position: relative;

    }

    .menu ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {

      position: absolute;

      right: 0;

      top: 0;

    }

    .menu ul.topnav.responsive li {

      float: left;

      display: block;

      background-color: #0099FF;

    }

    .menu ul.topnav.responsive li a {

      display: block;

      text-align: left;

      float: left;

    }

    .menu-wrap {

      background: #1a202c;

      overflow: hidden;

      width: 100%;

    }

    .menu {

      width: 70.2782%;

      height: 85px;

      margin-top: 80px;

      background-color: #0099FF;

      margin-right: auto;

      margin-bottom: 0;

      margin-left: auto;

    }

    .menu ul {

      background-color: #0099FF;

    }

    .menu ul li {

      list-style: none;

      float: left;

      width: auto;

      margin-right: -4px;

    }

    .menu ul li a {

      display: inline-block;

      height: 85px;

      line-height: 85px;

      padding-left: 30px;

      padding-right: 30px;

      font-size: 14px;

      font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;

      color: #ffffff;

      border-right: #0099FF solid 1px;

      text-transform: uppercase;

    }

    .menu ul li a:hover {

      background: #e1ece7;

      color: #1a202c;

    }

    .menu ul li a.active {

      background: #e1ece7;

      color: #1a202c;

    }
```

```html
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("topnav")[0].classList.toggle("responsive");
  }
</script>

<div class="menu-wrap">


  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="topnav">
      <li><a href="index.html" class="active">home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="about.html">about</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="services.html">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="register.html">Register </a>
      </li>
      <li class="icon">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
```

Comment: remove float in li & a tag

Comment: @LaljiTadhani it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set width of `li` to `100%`

```
ul.topnav.responsive li {
    width: 100%;
}
ul.topnav.responsive{
padding-left:0;
}
```

**Fixed Your snippet**

```css
.menu ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {

      display: none;

    }

    .menu ul.topnav li.icon {

      display: inline-block;

      float: right;

    }

    .menu ul.topnav.responsive {

      position: relative;

    }

    .menu ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {

      position: absolute;

      right: 0;

      top: 0;

    }

    .menu ul.topnav.responsive li {

      float: left;

      display: block;

      background-color: #0099FF;

    }

    .menu ul.topnav.responsive li a {

      display: block;

      text-align: left;

      float: left;

    }

    .menu-wrap {

      background: #1a202c;

      overflow: hidden;

      width: 100%;

    }

    .menu {

      width: 70.2782%;

      height: 85px;

      margin-top: 80px;

      background-color: #0099FF;

      margin-right: auto;

      margin-bottom: 0;

      margin-left: auto;

    }

    .menu ul {

      background-color: #0099FF;

    }

    .menu ul li {

      list-style: none;

      float: left;

      width: auto;

      margin-right: -4px;

    }

    .menu ul li a {

      display: inline-block;

      height: 85px;
      line-height: 85px;

      padding-left: 30px;

      padding-right: 30px;

      font-size: 14px;

      font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;

      color: #ffffff;

      border-right: #0099FF solid 1px;

      text-transform: uppercase;

    }

    .menu ul li a:hover {

      background: #e1ece7;

      color: #1a202c;

    }

    .menu ul li a.active {

      background: #e1ece7;

      color: #1a202c;

    }

ul.topnav.responsive li {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
ul.topnav.responsive{
padding-left:0;
}
ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("topnav")[0].classList.toggle("responsive");
  }
</script>

<div class="menu-wrap">


  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="topnav">
      <li><a href="index.html" class="active">home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="about.html">about</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="services.html">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="register.html">Register </a>
      </li>
      <li class="icon">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
```

Comment: Happy to help you @Darcy

Comment: The Home list is blocked when i press the navigation. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: OK i am trying to fix it

Comment: `ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    width: auto;
}` Fixed see this again @Darcy

Comment: it tooks 2 mins to do. By the way Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try clearing each list item `.menu ul li` adding `clear:both;` but you really should pull the nav trigger out of the list of menu items so that you can limit the size of your `ul` more easily and negate the use of clears entirely.

Try and HTML architecture like this:

```
<div class="menu-wrap">
<a class="menu-trigger" href="#" onclick="">&#9776;</a>
<div class="menu">
    <ul class="topnav">
        <li><a href="index.html" class="active">home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="about.html">about</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="register.html">Register </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .menu ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {

      display: none;

    }

    .menu ul.topnav li.icon {

      display: inline-block;

      float: right;

    }

    .menu ul.topnav.responsive {

      position: relative;

    }

    .menu ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {

      position: absolute;

      right: 0;

      top: 0;

    }

    .menu ul.topnav.responsive li {
    display: block;

      background-color: #0099FF;

    }

    .menu ul.topnav.responsive li a {

      display: block;

      text-align: left;

     

    }

    .menu-wrap {

      background: #1a202c;

      overflow: hidden;

      width: 100%;

    }

    .menu {

      width: 70.2782%;

     /* height: 85px;*/

      margin-top: 80px;

      background-color: #0099FF;

      margin-right: auto;

      margin-bottom: 0;

      margin-left: auto;

    }

    .menu ul {

      background-color: #0099FF;

    }

    .menu ul li {

      list-style: none;

     
      width: auto;

      margin-right: -4px;

    }

    .menu ul li a {

      display: inline-block;

      height: 85px;

      line-height: 85px;

      padding-left: 30px;

      padding-right: 30px;

      font-size: 14px;

      font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;

      color: #ffffff;

      border-right: #0099FF solid 1px;

      text-transform: uppercase;

    }

    .menu ul li a:hover {

      background: #e1ece7;

      color: #1a202c;

    }

    .menu ul li a.active {

      background: #e1ece7;

      color: #1a202c;

    }
```

```html
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("topnav")[0].classList.toggle("responsive");
  }
</script>

<div class="menu-wrap">


  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="topnav">
      <li><a href="index.html" class="active">home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="about.html">about</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="services.html">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="register.html">Register </a>
      </li>
      <li class="icon">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.menu ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {
 display: none;
}
.menu ul.topnav li.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.menu ul.topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
}
.menu ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
}
.menu ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    width:100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #0099FF;
}
.menu ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
.menu ul.topnav.responsive li.icon a {
    float:right;
    background: #016fb9;
}
.menu ul.topnav.responsive li.icon a:hover {
    color:#fff;
}
.menu-wrap {
    background: #1a202c;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
.menu {
    width: 70.2782%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 80px;
    background-color: #0099FF;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.menu ul {
    background-color: #0099FF;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    float:none;
    padding-left:0;
    position:relative;
}
.menu ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
}
.menu ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 85px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-right: #0099FF solid 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.menu ul li a:hover {
    background: #e1ece7;
    color: #1a202c;
}
.menu ul li a.active {
    background: #e1ece7;
    color: #1a202c;
}
</style>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("topnav")[0].classList.toggle("responsive");
  }
</script>
<div class="menu-wrap">
<div class="menu">
<ul class="topnav">
  <li><a href="index.html" class="active">home</a> </li>
  <li><a href="about.html">about</a> </li>
  <li><a href="services.html">Services</a> </li>
  <li><a href="register.html">Register </a> </li>
  <li class="icon"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a> </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

please find the same example in [js fiddle][https://jsfiddle.net/yhq1pzhj/][1](https://jsfiddle.net/yhq1pzhj/)

```
<script>
    function openNav() {
        $("#mySidenav").css('width', '150px');
    }

    function closeNav() {
        $("#mySidenav").css('width', '0px');
    }

</script>
<div>
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">X</a>
        <a href="index.html" class="active">home</a>
        <a href="about.html">about</a>

        <a href="services.html">Services</a>

        <a href="register.html">Register </a>
    </div>

    <i class="fa fa-bars" style="font-size:32px;cursor:pointer;padding-left: 35px;padding-top: 15px;" onclick="javascript:openNav()"></i></div>
```

======css======

```
.sidenav {
    /* height: 100%; */
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    /* top: 0;
    left: 0; */
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}

.sidenav a:hover,
.offcanvas a:focus {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
    .sidenav a {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}
```